# How to copy and empty a MySQL table daily?

Tags: mysql

I have a table named chat. I want to copy the contents to chat_archive and empty the contents of chat every day. Chat messages will still be flowing into chat at the time of copy. How can I accomplish this without lagging ongoing operations on the chat table?

Comment: Any solution will cause the incoming transactions to queue up. The trick is to minimize that amount of time.

Comment: a better method might be to append the rows of chat to chat_archive via a trigger. the trigger _should_ only add a small overhead to the database, and, then you can truncate the table daily.

Comment: Could you post how to do this with a trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the chat and delete it in a transaction, so that you don't lose anything between the two steps.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO chat_archive 
    SELECT * FROM chat;
DELETE FROM chat;
COMMIT;
```

If you have an auto-increment ID column, make sure you use should use `DELETE FROM chat;` rather than `TRUNCATE chat;`, since the latter will reset the auto-increment to `0`. `TRUNCATE` also auto-commits the transaction.